# Echo out a php file

Tags: php

I'm trying to open up my "index.php" file when I log-in on my website with the correct info but I keep getting errors.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbase.php';

$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid = '$uid' AND pwd = '$pwd'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "Your username or password is incorrect!";
}
else 
    {
   echo fgets($index);

}
```

Comment: maybe share the errors that you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also consider using prepared statements and PDO. Prepared statements will help prevent against [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
Your dbase.php  will be like

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourDBName', 'username', 'password');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Then your implementation

```
include 'dbase.php';

$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `uid` = :uid AND `pwd` = :pwd";
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$userData = [
    'uid'=>$uid,
    'pwd'=>$pwd
];

$statement->execute($userData);

if($statement->rowCount() > 0){
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}else{
    echo "Your username or password is wrong!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **else** condition block, redirect to index file

```
if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "Your username or password is incorrect!";
}
else 
    {
   header("location: index.php");
   exit();

}
```